I get a 'testContextFactory is null' error when running a citrusframework(4.3.3) junit5 test (within a springboot app). How to resolve this issue
I am new with the citrus framework and trying to write an http integration test (junit5) within a spring boot 3.3.5 application.
Based on the sample citrus framework code I've added the contextConfiguration with my endpointConfig.class. I also try to add org.citrusframework.config.CitrusSpringConfig to the contextConfiguration, but this dependecy was missing. Does anyone know How to resolve this problem.
import static org.citrusframework.actions.EchoAction.Builder.echo;

import org.citrusframework.TestCaseRunner;
import org.citrusframework.annotations.CitrusResource;
import org.citrusframework.annotations.CitrusTest;
import org.citrusframework.junit.jupiter.spring.CitrusSpringSupport;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

@CitrusSpringSupport
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {  EndPointConfig.class })
class IntegratieTest {

    @CitrusResource
    TestCaseRunner runner;

    @Test
    @CitrusTest
    void testRequest() {
        runner.description("First example showing the basic Java DSL!");
        runner.variable("user","mario");
        runner.$(echo("hello"));

    }
}

When running this test I get the following error 'Cannot invoke "org.citrusframework.context.TestContextFactory.getObject()" because "this.testContextFactory" is null'
Cannot invoke "org.citrusframework.context.TestContextFactory.getObject()" because "this.testContextFactory" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.citrusframework.context.TestContextFactory.getObject()" because "this.testContextFactory" is null
    at org.citrusframework.CitrusContext.createTestContext(CitrusContext.java:172)
    at org.citrusframework.junit.jupiter.CitrusExtensionHelper.lambda$getTestContext$4(CitrusExtensionHelper.java:182)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.store.NamespacedHierarchicalStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$5(NamespacedHierarchicalStore.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.store.NamespacedHierarchicalStore$MemoizingSupplier.computeValue(NamespacedHierarchicalStore.java:372)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.store.NamespacedHierarchicalStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(NamespacedHierarchicalStore.java:361)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.store.NamespacedHierarchicalStore$StoredValue.evaluate(NamespacedHierarchicalStore.java:308)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.store.NamespacedHierarchicalStore$StoredValue.access$200(NamespacedHierarchicalStore.java:287)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.store.NamespacedHierarchicalStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespacedHierarchicalStore.java:149)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.store.NamespacedHierarchicalStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespacedHierarchicalStore.java:168)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$3(NamespaceAwareStore.java:66)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.accessStore(NamespaceAwareStore.java:90)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespaceAwareStore.java:65)
    at org.citrusframework.junit.jupiter.CitrusExtensionHelper.getTestContext(CitrusExtensionHelper.java:181)
    at org.citrusframework.junit.jupiter.CitrusExtension.interceptTestMethod(CitrusExtension.java:141)
    at org.citrusframework.junit.jupiter.spring.CitrusSpringExtension.interceptTestMethod(CitrusSpringExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:218)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:139)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:156)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:146)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:144)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:100)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:160)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:146)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:144)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:100)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:160)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:146)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:144)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:100)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:119)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:66)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)


There is a dependency missing 'org.citrusframework:citrus-spring-integration' in the build.gradle. You can then add CitrusSpringConfig to the @ContextConfiguration like below.
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {  CitrusSpringConfig.class, EndPointConfig.class })

With this change I was able to run this integration test.
Below the list of all the citrus dependencies used:
integrationTestImplementation group: 'org.citrusframework', name: 'citrus-base', version: citrus_version  
        integrationTestImplementation group: 'org.citrusframework', name: 'citrus-http', version: citrus_version  
        integrationTestImplementation group: 'org.citrusframework', name: 'citrus-junit5', version: citrus_version  
        integrationTestImplementation group: 'org.citrusframework', name: 'citrus-spring', version: citrus_version  
        integrationTestImplementation group: 'org.citrusframework', name: 'citrus-spring-integration', version: citrus_version  
        integrationTestImplementation group: 'org.citrusframework', name: 'citrus-validation-json', version: citrus_version  
        integrationTestImplementation group: 'org.citrusframework', name: 'citrus-endpoint-catalog', version: citrus_version  

